# React Navigation Header change with screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator

I have a StackNavigation and want a default `Header` (component Header) and want that "deep pages" shows up with the default header generated for the React Navigation.

In my index page `**Index**`, just wanted the Header component(first header)...but shows up another blank header:

[image]

In my "deep page" `**Teste**` just want the title and back button autogenarated by RNav(second header)...but the first header shows up.

[image]

This is my nav config:

```
const RootNavigator = StackNavigator({
    Welcome: {screen: Welcome},
    User: {
        screen: TabNavigator({
            Clientes: {
                screen: StackNavigator({
                    Index: {screen: Clientes},
                    Teste: {
                        screen: Teste,
                        header: undefined
                    }
                }, {
                    header: null,
                    navigationOptions: {
                        tabBarIcon: () => (
                            <Icon name="list-alt" size={22} color="#ffffff" />
                        )
                    }
                })
            },
            Opcoes: { screen: Opcoes }
        }, {
            tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
            tabBarOptions: {
                showLabel: false,
                activeTintColor: '#fff',
                showIcon: true,
                inactiveTintColor: '#ccc',
                indicatorStyle: {
                    backgroundColor: '#ccc'
                },
                style: {
                    backgroundColor: '#536878'
                }
            }
        })
    },
}, {
    initialRouteName: 'User',
    navigationOptions: {
        header: props => <Header {...props} />
    }
});

export default RootNavigator;
```

Comment: Did answer bellow help anyhow?

Comment: From my experience, don't mess up with nested Navigator thing, you have to do it tricky even if it works. Use NativeBase instead, you'll have more control to the header and more. https://nativebase.io/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every StackNavigator brings one header, first one is from `RootNavigator = StackNavigator({` and bottom one that you see is coming from `Clientes: { screen: StackNavigator({`.

First of all, seams `header: null` in your `Clientes: { screen: StackNavigator({` doesn't have any effect. You should try `headerMode: 'none'` instead, this will remove the blank header from `Index` but also header from `Teste` with the title and back button, which is doesn't solve all your problems.

So I would suggest different navigators structure:

```
RootNavigator(StackNavigator)
- Welcome
- Index
- Teste
- User(TabNavigator)
    - Clientes 
    - Opcoes
```

What you should you do next is set different header (default one, with back button) for `Teste` inside component itself, something like this:

```
import { Header } from 'react-navigation';

Teste.navigationOptions = ({ navigation, screenProps }) => ({
    return {
        header: <Header {...screenProps} {...navigation} />
    }
});
```

You can even make your own header Component and use it in Teste.navigationOptions.